# data structure of reactjs built project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, structure

I am new to react, redux and webpack and I have several problems. I started with "simpe-redux-boilerplate". My project structure is:

```
 --src
   --containers
   --index.js
   --...
 --php
 --vendor
 --janguage.json
```

First, I need to use janguage.json from my App.js in container directory without bundling, so I am not importing it but fetching

```
 fetch('language.json')...
```

I am able to import it with path './../../language.json', but for fetching this path is not working. Which is the right path?

Second, I am using php for server requests (php and other directories). Unfortunately, these directories are not included in my build. How to add them? Move to src directory doesn't work.

My webpack prod configuration:

```
 entry: [
       './src/index',
 ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `fetch`, you could try `import('../../language.json').then(...)`. That will give you a split point and roughly the same result.

Comment: it is not valid construction

Comment: What do you mean? Support was added in webpack 2. https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/code-splitting/

Comment: cool, I has older version of webpack. But file "language.json" is not json but js file :/

Comment: It should not matter. It can be json/js and it should work (esp. in webpack 2). In webpack 1 you should use `require.ensure` and **json-loader** (if you plan on loading JSON).

Comment: Import uses the file system, but fetch will require that you fetch from a URL on your site, so you may need to place this file in a public folder, or static folder.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen I know, I google it, changed it, and now the file is separated from main bundle, but its name is 0.bundle.js and not language.json (or .js). I have no idea where to change it in webpack configuration file.

Comment: @Toby It's the key information for me :) But it is related to my second question - how to access these directories from? I seems that directories out of src directory are ignored (e.g. dir. php)

Comment: You can manually place a folder on your webserver somewhere, so long as you're able to browse to that location using a web browser, fetch will work. However, then it is a matter of knowing your web server config..

Comment: A better all around solution would be to use create-react-app by Facebook - it solves a great deal of these issues, allowing you to focus on simply writing your app.